# How to print between multiple dates in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to run mysql query for average vacation hours and sick leaves for the employees that were born

•   Between the years 1960 and 1969

•   Between the years 1970 and 1979

•   Between the years 1980 and 1989

```
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours)
FROM HumanResources.employee
WHERE BirthDate BETWEEN '1960-1-1' AND '1969-12-31' 
  OR  BirthDate BETWEEN '1970-1-1' AND '1979-12-31' 
  OR  BirthDate BETWEEN '1980-1-1' AND '1980-12-31'


Output 
44 49
```

I want output for individual decade.
something like this.

```
Output
44 49
44 43
42 47
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify like this when the years are continuous

```
SELECT Extract(YEAR FROM BirthDate) ,
       Avg(VacationHours),
       Avg(SickLeaveHours)
FROM   HumanResources.employee
WHERE  BirthDate BETWEEN '1960-1-1' AND '1980-12-31'
GROUP BY Extract(YEAR FROM BirthDate)
```

Comment: Using between for Date Comparison in SQL Server will give inappropriate results. Gordon's approach is a better way. Refer below links. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common and https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: @RGS - That is true when the `dates` have `time` part in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` with `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN BirthDate BETWEEN '1960-01-01' AND '1969-12-31' THEN '1960s'
             WHEN BirthDate BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1979-12-31' THEN '1970s'
             WHEN BirthDate BETWEEN '1980-01-01' AND '1980-12-31' THEN '1980s'
        END) as decade,
       AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours)
FROM HumanResources.employee
WHERE BirthDate >= '1960-01-01' AND BirthDate < '1990-01-01'
GROUP BY decade
ORDER BY decade;
```

MySQL permits you to use a column alias for `GROUP BY`.  Some databases require that you repeat the expression.